# how to synchronize time on farm of windows 2003 servers?

Tags: windows-server-2003, time-server

I would like to load balance a group of windows 2003 servers.
They are not on a domain, and I am not using active directory.

I would like the synchronize the time for these boxes.

What is the best way of doing this?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`net time /setsntp:pool.ntp.org`

[Reference](http://www.pool.ntp.org/en/use.html) 
<sub>Note: This does **not** work for domain-joined computers.</sub>